# Is The A-Team on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Perhaps some clarification is appropriate. The series features many components that you usually find in science fiction (maybe also in fantasy, but I've no clue about that).

The setting is typically a dystopia, sometimes even sub-societies that resemble full-fledged dictatorship.
A small crew, against all odds, and with almost super-human intellect (Hannibal/Face) and ingenuity (Murdoc/B.A.) manages to free the oppressed and helpless people using some improvised technology (can it get more science fiction there?).
Last but not least, they manage to fine-tune their attacks so to not (seriously) hurt anybody, but they're not using phasers (on a stun setting) but MGs (without basic aiming skills).

Comment: I'd consider it Sci Fi. If we had a live/beta TV show Q/A site I'd suggest asking it there instead, but we don't. If the My Little Pony question was on topic here (it IS fantasy) then I believe the A-Team is reasonable from your description; I haven't seen the show myself.

Comment: @BenBrocka the Movies site (which is in public beta) has moved recently to include television in its scope.

Comment: @IanPugsley that would seem most appropriate then, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: It's definitely fantasy.  How else do you explain millions of bullets and rockets and explosions and no one dies?

Comment: I don't think it is, but **Knight Rider** *definitely* is!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd recommend asking A-Team questions on the beta [Movies.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) site which now has TV shows as being on topic.

Answer (score 10):

As someone who has seen every episode, I don't see how you can consider *The A-Team* as science fiction or fantasy.  While it's incredible in terms of being removed from reality, it's more in either the action or suspense genre.